# Is using [intptr]::Size to check 32bits vs 64bits relevant?

Tags: windows

In a deployment Powershell script, made by an editor, it use the following lines to determine if the server is 32 bits or 64 bits and download the appropriate package.

```
if ( [intptr]::Size -eq 8 ) { 
   $sourceUrl=-join($baseurl, "software/agent/Windows/x86_64/") }
else {
   $sourceUrl=-join($baseurl, "software/agent/Windows/i386/") }
```

I have found one example of [intptr]::Size returning value 4 and the system is 64 bits on a Windows 2008 R2 server.

So should I consider the above method not right ? And which alternative can I use ?

Comment: That (probably) checks whether the powershell interpreter you're using is 32bit or 64bit. Are you running 32bit powershell on the 64bit system?

Comment: @Mat, yes it's exactly that, on a 64 bits OS the result will depend of the powershell interpreter ! So the editor method is not reliable at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem) { 
  $sourceUrl=-join($baseurl, "software/agent/Windows/x86_64/")  
}
else {
  $sourceUrl=-join($baseurl, "software/agent/Windows/i386/")  
}
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61396435/how-do-i-check-the-os-architecture32-or-64-bit-using-powershell